# Receiving "400 Bad Request" for /oauth/access_token

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have approved for public_content clientId. To get access token, I send a request to www.instagram.com:

```
GET /oauth/authorize?client_id=MyClientId&redirect_uri=MyRedirectURL&response_type=code&scope=likes+comments+public_content HTTP/1.1`
```

After authentication, the browser redirects me to MyRedirectURL and I can get the code from the URL.

With this code I send a request to api.instagram.com:

```
/oauth/access_token HTTP/1.1
```

client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MyClientSecret&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=MyRedirectURL&code=CodeFromURL`

But sometimes I get response HTTP/1.1 **400 Bad Request**.
 This situation continues for a few hours, and sometimes for a day. It is interesting that the problem is very unstable. I may have two client apps that make identical requests, and one app will work fine, while the other will fail at the same time. Looks like it is a problem somewhere in the Instagram infrastructure.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I also have two apps using the same API credentials, maybe it has something to do with that

Comment: I have a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898044/instagram-api-prevents-redirection-to-ios-app-upon-successful-login

Comment: still having this issue today.  Anyone found a resolution or had an official response from Instagram? I submitted a bug report via the dev console

Comment: i am getting `{
  "code": 400,
  "error_type": "OAuthException",
  "error_message": "You must provide a client_id"
}`

Comment: Changing ContentType to x-www-form-urlencoded resolves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram is no longer supporting custom schemas for your callback urls. That was my problem, I changed it to https and the problem was solved.

Comment: Do you have a link to an official statement?

Comment: Not that I've seen, but there have been a lot of changes in their terms and other things recently.

Comment: If you dont have any link to official statement then how can you be so sure ?

Comment: so how do you redirect back to your application without a custom scheme?

Comment: how do we redirect back to our app then?

Comment: I use http/https in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefer [this document](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/) of Instagram.

> You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad
>   Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your app.
>   These errors are unrelated to rate limiting.

Comment: Is there any way to recognize this situation?

Comment: I am not sure, but you don't have any way to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like , we can not use `http://localhost/...` in call back url. Instagram may have restricted it.

It worked for me, when I have added live Ip of my aws server. for example `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/..` instead of localhost.